# Why is LDAP trying to connect by hostname instead of localhost?

Tags: hostname, ldap

I have set up an LDAP server on `localhost` and generated certificate with `CN=localhost`. But when I run the command

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost -D "..." -w password -ZZ -d1
```

I get the error

```
...
TLS: hostname (sithViewcy) does not match common name in certificate     (localhost).
ldap_err2string
ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
    additional info: TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer     certificate
...
```

"sithViewcy" is in my /etc/hostname

Certificate is ok

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/certs/avi9526.guest_ldap.crt -noout -text | grep CN=
```

:

```
    Issuer: C=..., ST=..., L=..., O=..., OU=CA, CN=avi9526.guest
    Subject: C=..., ST=.., L=.., O=..., OU=LDAP, CN=localhost
```

Why does LDAP the client try to connect by `/etc/hostname` and not the provided name `localhost`?

Comment: Because the server know the hostname. You might try to bind it only to localhost.